# Loop through dependent variables in GLM model when an independent variable fulfill a condition

Tags: r, loops, subset, lapply, glm

I have code to loop a logistic regression over several selected dependant variables (called outcome1-4). I would like to only run the model if a condition in an independent variable is met. Let's say I want at least two females for each outcome and type combination.

Dummy data:

```
set.seed(5)
df <- data.frame(
  id = c(1:100),
  age = sample(20:80, 100, replace = TRUE),
  sex = sample(c("M", "F"), 100, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.7, 0.3)),
  type = sample(letters[1:4], 100, replace = TRUE),
  outcome1 = sample(c(0L, 1L), 100, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.68, 0.32)),
  outcome2 = sample(c(0L, 1L), 100, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.65, 0.35)),
  outcome3 = sample(c(0L, 1L), 100, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.60, 0.40)),
  outcome4 = sample(c(0L, 1L), 100, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.45, 0.55)))
```

Code to loop GLM (cred to https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/codefragments/looping_strings/):

```
outcomelist <- names(df)[5:8]
modelall <- lapply(outcomelist, function(x) {
  glm(substitute(i ~ type + sex, list(i = as.name(x))), family = "binomial", data = df)})
```

I have found lots of questions concerning the loop but not any with additional condition. I am thinking subset but not being a pro on lapply yet I don't know where to put it.

If this is not an additional question I would like each model to be named the name of the outcome variable in the list (instead of 1 to 4) since it otherwise will be difficult to keep track of the models when the condition is added.

Appreciate any help!

Comment: " I would like to only run the model if a condition in an independent variable is met" this means running outcome 1 - 4 independently right?

Comment: you already have it in modelall

Comment: @StupidWolf yes, running all independently, but there need to be at least 2 females in each type (a,b,c,d) when each outcome is 1 to run the model. I might have explained it in a bad way in the question. The number 2 here is just for the example.

Comment: ok my bad.. I read the question too quickly. so you want to run it if there's at least two per combination group. Hmmm sorry, just to ask, you are excluding the cases when say it's all outcome=0 for type = a ?

Comment: All cases (rows) stay in the df but the model is not run for those outcomes where females are less then two given outcome == 1 for each type. If this can be checked after all models been run that is fine too but I am not yet so good at lists so I cannot figure it out. I might do as @Mr. Zen propose below to clean the outcomes that don't meet the condition from the df first. I have been struggeling with this for a while weather to keep the df as long and use `group_by` but the `id` should only be included once for each outcome (0/1) so in the end I decided to `spread` it and one-hot encode it.

Comment: Sorry I cannot edit my comment. It should be "at least two" where I wrote less then two. .

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to clean the data prior to running `lapply()`:

```
df.new <- df

for(ii in 1:length(outcomelist)){

temp <- outcomelist[ii]

# check the condition for outcome variable ii
condition <- any(aggregate(df$sex=="F", by=list(df$type, df[,temp]), FUN="sum")$x < 2)

if(condition){

# if the condition is met, remove the variable from df and outcomelist  

df.new[,temp]   <- NULL
outcomelist[ii] <- NA

}

}

# lose irrelevant outcomes
outcomelist <- na.omit(outcomelist)

modelall <- lapply(outcomelist, function(x) {
  glm(substitute(i ~ type + sex, list(i = as.name(x))), family = "binomial", data = df.new)})


# name the list
names(modelall) <- outcomelist
```

Comment: Yes, cleaning before is definately an option. I was probably not clear in my question because the code provided remove all outcome variables. If running `df %>% group_by(sex, type, outcome4) %>% summarise(n = length(sex))` there are at least 2 females for each type. Or maybe I am missing something.

Comment: My code removes outcomes 2 and 3 because in these outcomes, there are less than two females by type and outcome (1/0). Can you provide some example of what your goal is?

Comment: After I run your code from `df.new` to the end of the `for` loop my `outcomelist` is `c(NA, NA, NA, NA)` so `outcomelist <- na.omit(outcomelist)` removes all outcomes and the model has nothing to run. After I trialled the code I have updated the `condition` from `$x < 2` to `$x < 3` just so we both talk about at least two females. I'm still learning about lists so maybe I just don't get it. Naming the list was a bit too easy I realise.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. The code removes outcomes 2 and 3 from the data set. For instance, for outcome 2, only 1 female is in the type a / outcome 1 group. Hence, my code drops that outcome.

Comment: Ok, can it have anything to do with set.seed? Also thinking if I have a package that mask something but it looks to me that it is only `aggregate` that could be the problem. I'll check everything again and otherwise accept your answer anyway.